# ASP.NET mvc4 controller action not invoked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, onclick, forms, http-post

I have the following methods defined in the HomeController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Validate(AccountRegisterModel accountRegisterModel)
{
   // do something
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AccountRegisterModel accountRegisterModel)
{
   // do something else
}
```

I have these lines of HTML defined in the View.

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Validate", "Home")'"/>
<input name="validate" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Validate", "Home")'"/>
```

When I run the application and click on both buttons, the Create action on the controller is always invoked.  What is the deal here?

I am working with the default routing defined as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both inputs have a `type=submit`, so after the `onclick` event, both call the parent form.

Try capturing the `onclick` event on each `input` with `stopPropagation()` or just `return false;`

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" 
    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Validate", "Home")'; return false;"/>
<input name="validate" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" 
    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Validate", "Home")'; return false;"/
```